# How Floating Point precision setting works

Tags: c++, precision, floating

I have seen many answers on how to set precision for floating point numbers and everywhere we are doing something like below :

```
double RoundDouble(double doValue,int nPrecision)
{
    return (floor((doValue*pow(10,nPrecision)+0.5))/pow(10,nPrecision));
}
```

I could not understand how multiplying and dividing by almost equal numbers will set precision correctly ? can anybody explain in detail

Comment: you can look for explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Limits of f.p. precision was not build by "bad ugly man", by has deep reason. To be the true, hard to speak about precision in 'decimal' terms, not that way

Comment: By "precision", I believe the author refers to decimal places, and _not_ significant figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just using whole-number rounding to achieve the trick that we all learned at school for cutting off at some number of decimal places: take the first N digits after the decimal, and round the right-most one up or down.

If you think about this in rounding 12.3456 to 2 decimal places, you naturally expect the result to be 12.35, because the '4' is the right-most of the two digits and gets rounded up by the '5' that follows.

Now, to achieve this with math we utilize `floor` to achieve the rounding (actually you can utilize `std::round` instead).  But that will take us to a whole number and we'll lose all the fractional part.

To avoid that, we first multiply by 100, moving all the interesting parts into the whole number realm:

```
1234.56
```

If you round this number to the nearest whole value with either `std::floor(x+0.5)` or `std::round(x)`, you then get:

```
1235.0
```

Finally, dividing this by 100 gives you the number rounded (yes, remember we rounded it) to two decimal places:

```
12.35
```

Hopefully you now see what's going on with the call to `pow`.  By raising 10 to the power of `nPrecision`, we get a scaling factor that will provide that many decimal places after rounding, when using this trick.  In this case, we wanted 2, and `pow(10,2)` is 100.

I took the liberty of cleaning up your function for readability:

```
double RoundDouble(double doValue, int nPrecision)
{
    double scale_factor = pow(10.0, static_cast<double>(nPrecision));
    return std::round(doValue * scale_factor) / scale_factor;
}
```

Comment: but how it is ensured that double that is returned will exactly contain 12.35 and not 12.350000001

Comment: It doesn't.  Was that actually the question?

Comment: Yes that is something i want to know because i am trying to convert 50.28999999999999 upto 9 decimal places and still getting 50.289999999 in calling function

Comment: If this is purely for displaying the value as text?

Comment: In that case, you could use `std::ostringstream` with IO manipulators: `std::ostringstream ss; ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(nPrecision) << doValue; std::string strval( ss.str() );`

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step-by-step.

1. `x = doValue * pow(10, nPrecision)` — `nPrecision` digits are shifted to integral part, others stay in fractal part;
2. `y = floor(x + 0.5)` — round to integral part (if `x` is non-negative);
3. `z = y / pow(10, nPrecision)` — shift `nPrecision` digits back to fractal part.

Comment: The standard for rounding negatives is to share equal weight across the zero region, and so -0.49 should round to 0.  Read more about [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).  So `floor(x + 0.5)` is actually correct.

Comment: @paddy Yes, I've mixed with `int(x + 0.5)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented above but If we debug it using the some sample input then something like below will happen:

```
// say we have 5.89162 and we want it to 2 decimal places 5.89 so
RoundDouble(5.89162,2)
{
return (floor(5.89162*pow(10,2)+0.5))/pow(10,2);
/* which will look like
    floor((5.89162x100+0.5)/100)
     floor(589.662/100)
     floor(5.89662)
and floor function will bound it to 5 it means the output will be 5 instead of 5.89*/
}
```

Comment: you have not checked brackets correctly pow(10,2) is not part of floor,so this will return 5.89 not 5

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. Floating point doesn't have decimal places. It has binary places, and they are incommensurable with decimal places. All it does is provide an approximation.

For proof see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421).

If you want decimal places accurately you have to use a decimal radix.